# Android on Eclipse LogCat tag ServiceManager with text Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger keep looping

Tags: android, eclipse, loops, logging, logcat

I'm new in Android development. I'm just trying to create button on emulator with tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtmHURWKCmg&feature=youtu.be)  with `Log.d` commend. So I see my logcat and found something looping forever.

- Level = I
- PID = 1706
- TID = 1720
- Application = system_process
- Tag = ServiceManager
- Text = Waiting for service SurfaceSlinger...

with following

- Level = I
- PID = 579
- TID = 579
- Application = (blank)
- Tag = PGA
- Text = Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 579, tid = 579

and after about 5 times looping, another looping come out with red text color

- Level = E
- PID =  6157
- TID = 6157
- Application = (blank)
- Tag = qemu
- Text = setting qemu logfile name to /storage/sdcard/arm-logs/arm-runtime.1 og prop_val ='crash'

Either with emulator running or not, this log always came out.
Can someone help me how to fix it?

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you

Comment: Hey friend, did you ever found the solution?? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this same problem, It was because I had running in the background an android emulator outside of eclipse, in my case was the bluestacks emulator, when I stopped it my LogCat stopped printing that loop message.

You should use this command in the adb command line, to use the adb command line, go to this path in your console;  this is in windows.

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

And when you are in that folder use this command `adb devices` this command should print the devices you have.

After this use this command with the port number of the emulator you want to stop `adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill` in my case was the 5554.

In my case in case you also have bluestacks, to stopped the bluestack emulator in windows from staring automatically I followed this steps.

Go to msconfig, in msconfig go to the services tab, uncheck the bluestacks android service and bluestacks log rotator service, then go to the startup tab and uncheck bluestacks from starting automatically, then restart your computer.

This link worth a reading about how to stop emulators: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/

And this link about how to stop bluestack emulator more detail it:
http://www.oaultimate.com/computers/computer-slow-boot-and-disable-bluestacks-startup.html

Comment: Thanks a lot .I uninstalled bluestacks ,now this error is not coming and im able to run the app in my emulator